# Python: Moving letters within the alphabet in a string

Tags: python, string, for-loop, whitespace

I've been working in Python and have been trying to move all letters in a string n spaces in the alphabet, however I've run into a fair amount of errors.

```
print("Cryptography")
userInput = str(input("Write anything that you'd like to encrypt here: "))
userNumberInput = int(input("Please choose a number without decimals here: "))
userInput = userInput.lower()
wordCount = userInput.split()
loopRunner = int(0)
letterCount = list()
for word in range(len(wordCount)):
    letterCount.insert(loopRunner,len(wordCount[loopRunner]))
    print(letterCount[loopRunner])
    loopRunner = loopRunner + 1

outputString = "" .join((chr(97 + (ord(letter) -97 + userNumberInput) % 26) for letter in userInput))
loopRunner = 0
for word in range(len(wordCount)):
    outputString2 = [outputString[i:i+letterCount[loopRunner]] for i in range (0, len(outputString), letterCount[loopRunner])]
    loopRunner = loopRunner + 1
finalResult = " " .join(outputString2)
print(finalResult)
```

So far it does what I need it to do, however when I try to run this, it also seems to count spaces as letters and I have no idea how to exclude them, while keeping them in the final result just as they are.

Another thing that I'd like to know is if there is any way for me to keep the letters from being turned into lowercase ones and keep the code functional?

I've been trying things for hours but haven't been able to come upon a good solution.

Comment: Do you want to change spaces as well or just alter the letters and keep the spaces where they are as spaces?

Comment: I want to alter the letters and keep the spaces where they are as spaces. How would I go about storing the position of a space? I understand the overall procedure, but I do not know where I'd even start in regards to coding it. Could you give me a quick example?

Comment: I'm working on a solution but the just of it could look like this:
at the start:
save the index location of all spaces in a list
userInput = userInput.replace(' ', '')
and at the end add spaces at those index locations again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this without editing what you have already is to index all the locations where spaces are and save those index locations as a string. Please note my example is messy and you should try to implement without a try/except structure.

```
n = 0
spacesLocation = []
while(True):
    try:
        spacesLocation.append(userInput.index(' '))
        userInput = userInput.replace(' ', '', 1)
        n+=1
    except:
        n = 0
        break
```

Then at the end add them back in:

```
while(n < len(spacesLocation)):#goes through where all the spaces are
    finalResult = finalResult[:spacesLocation[n]+n] + ' ' +finalResult[spacesLocation[n]+n:]#adds spaces where they go
    n+=1#re-iterates to go through where all the spaces should be
```

so your whole thing looks something like this:

```
print("Cryptography")
userInput = str(input("Write anything that you'd like to encrypt here: "))
n = 0
spacesLocation = []
while(True):
    try:
        spacesLocation.append(userInput.index(' '))
        userInput = userInput.replace(' ', '', 1)
        n+=1
    except:
        n = 0
        break
userNumberInput = int(input("Please choose a number without decimals here: "))
userInput = userInput.lower()
wordCount = userInput.split()
loopRunner = int(0)
letterCount = list()
for word in range(len(wordCount)):
    letterCount.insert(loopRunner,len(wordCount[loopRunner]))
    print(letterCount[loopRunner])
    loopRunner = loopRunner + 1

outputString = "" .join((chr(97 + (ord(letter) -97 + userNumberInput) % 26) for letter in userInput))
loopRunner = 0
for word in range(len(wordCount)):
    outputString2 = [outputString[i:i+letterCount[loopRunner]] for i in range (0, len(outputString), letterCount[loopRunner])]
    loopRunner = loopRunner + 1
finalResult = " " .join(outputString2)
while(n < len(spacesLocation)):
    finalResult = finalResult[:spacesLocation[n]+n] + ' ' +finalResult[spacesLocation[n]+n:]
    n+=1
print(finalResult)
```

Comment if you have any questions about how that works because stackoverflow is meant to increase understanding, not just give solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I've been looking for, am I correct in assuming/understanding that this code can be tuned to also store the index locations of capital letters, or any character at all so that I may for example have helLo world with a userNumberInput of 2 turn out as jgnNq yqtnf instead of jgnnq yqtnf?

Comment: you could modify it to do that but it'd be a bit more of a hassle.

Comment: I realised that after toying around with it a little. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use string module and shift function as follows:

```
import string

def shift():
    userInput = input("Write anything that you'd like to encrypt here: ")
    userNumberInput = int(input("Please choose a number without decimals here: "))
    letters=' '+string.ascii_letters
    if userNumberInput > len(letters): userNumberInput = userNumberInput%len(letters)
    d={k:v for k,v in zip(letters,' '+letters[userNumberInput:]+letters[:userNumberInput])}
    return ''.join([x.replace(x,d[x]) for x in userInput])
```

Function unchange space position and shift all letters in userInput exactly userNumberInput number

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! It does what I need it to do and grants me a fair amount of insight regarding other options when it comes to coding. :)